# Flutter, pass datetime value to a method

Tags: android, flutter, datepicker

I currently have a page where i can select a date range, after that i have a search bar, and then a listview.
When i select dates, and i click on submit, dates are displayed.
Now i need to pass those dates to a method, but it is received as null.
It seems that i forget something to be able to use this variable..

```
class HistoriquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final String namespace;

  const HistoriquePage({Key? key, required this.title, required this.namespace})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HistoriquePageState createState() => _HistoriquePageState();
}

class _HistoriquePageState extends State<HistoriquePage> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> myFormKey = new GlobalKey();
  DateTimeRange? dateRange;
  Post? user;

  void _submitForm() {
    final FormState? form = myFormKey.currentState;
    form!.save();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Form(
            key: myFormKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: SafeArea(
                    child: DateRangeField(
                        enabled: true,
                        initialValue: DateTimeRange(
                            start: DateTime.parse("2020-01-01"),
                            end: DateTime.now()),
                        firstDate: new DateTime(2020),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'Interval de temps pour la recherche',
                          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.date_range),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        ),
                        onSaved: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            dateRange = value!;
                          });
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  child: TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Select the namespace...',
                      ),
                      onChanged: (searchedValue) {
                        setState(() {
                          HistoriqueService.filterList(searchedValue,
                              dateRange: dateRange);
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: _submitForm,
                ),
                if (dateRange != null)
                  Text("Saved value is: ${dateRange.toString()}"),
                Expanded(child: DeploymentList())
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

class HistoriqueService {
  static Future<List<User>> filterList(String value,
      {DateTimeRange? dateRange}) async {
    print("value" + value);
    if (dateRange != null) {
      print("dateRange: " + dateRange.toString());
    }
    List<User> postsList = await HttpService.fetchHistorique();
    return postsList
        .where((user) => user.name.toLowerCase().contains(value.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you can do `historiqueService.yourFunction(dateRange)` in this case the `historiqueService` is made with `final HistoriqueService historiqueService = HistoriqueService()`

Comment: @SilkeNL This is already what i have here ; HistoriqueService.filterList(searchedValue,
                              dateRange: dateRange);

Comment: Are you sure it set the state right? Can you print dateRange in `onChanged: (searchedValue) { setState(() { HistoriqueService.filterList(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange); }); }),`

Comment: The state for the dataRange is above here : `onSaved: (value) {setState(() {
dateRange = value!;});`
As i said, i can see the value when i click on Submit

Comment: I understand but something isn't right in the code. To find out where, try printing dateRange in multiple places. Where is it a date and where is it null?

Comment: Text("Saved value is: ${dateRange.toString()}") is working, after i press the Submit button.
It is null in the filterList method.

Comment: The `filterList` function returns a  `Future`. Put the `async`  modifier to the `onChanged` function and the `await` keyword when you call the `filterList` function, like this: `onChanged: (searchedValue) async { setState(() { await HistoriqueService.filterList(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange); });}` . Hope this works!

Comment: @AbelRodríguez Hum no it breaks : `( [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: setState() callback argument returned a Future.
E/flutter (27540): The setState() method on _HistoriquePageState#7bf88 was called with a closure or method that returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".
E/flutter (27540): Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState(). `
daterange is not printed

Comment: The error states the problem and possible solution: `Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously update the state inside a call to setState().`

So maybe get the value for inside the setState first, then set the state for real?

Comment: Just put the `filterList` function outside the `setState` , like this: `onChanged: (searchedValue) async { await HistoriqueService.filterList(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange); setState(() {});}`. I already tested it and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using form in your class but it is not useful at all in this case.
I recommend you to remove the form, then you replace the onSaved by onChanged like that :

```
onChanged: (value) {
setState(() {
 dateRange = value!;
});
```

Create a method to send your searched value :

```
void _sendSearch(String value) {
    _debounce.run(() {
      setState(() {
        searchedValue = value;
      });
    });
  }
```

You can now replace your onChanged method for the namespace :

```
onChanged: _sendSearch
```

And finally replace your extanded method by this one ( now you give to your deploymentList the dateRangeand the searchedValue:

```
Expanded(child: DeploymentList(searchedValue, dateRange: dateRange))
```

So each time you change the daterange or the searched value, the component will be rebuilt.